# Build an Electrical Grid

Tags: fastest-code

## The Challenge

There are N cities aligned in a straight line. The i-th city is located `A[i]` kilometers to the right of the origin. No two cities will be in the same place.

You are going to build an electrical grid with some power plants. Power plants must be built inside a city. However, you are only allowed to build `K` (< N) power plants, so there will be some cities with no power plants in them. For each city with no power plants, you must build a cable between it and **the nearest city that has a power plant**.

For example, if there are three cities located at `0, 1, 2`, and only the city at `0` has a power plant, you need to build two cables, one from `2` to `0`(2km) and the other from `1` to `0`(1km), which have a total length of 3km.

Given `K` and positions of cities (`A`), you should compute the minimum kilometers of cable you need to build the grid.

## Example Testcases

```
K = 1, A = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] : 12 
# build power plant in the city at position 4, total length = 4 + 2 + 0 + 2 + 4 = 12

K = 3, A = [0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 30, 32] : 23
# build power plants in cities at positions 0, 10 and 22

K = 5, A = [0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14] : 3
# build power plants in all cities except those at positions 0, 3

K = 6, A = [0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 14, 15, 18, 29, 30, 38, 41, 45, 46, 49, 58, 66, 72, 83, 84] : 49
```

## Specifications

- You should implement a function or a program, which takes a positive integer `K` and a list of integers `A` in any form, and output/return an integer representing the answer.
- `A` is sorted in ascending order, and all elements are non-negative integers.
- `A[0] = 0`, and `A[N-1]` will be no more than 1000N.
- Note that the output will be in magnitude of 1000N<sup>2</sup>, so in larger cases, you may need 64-bit integers in some languages.
- Multithreading is **not** allowed (I will set the affinity of your program to only 1 core when judging). Compiler optimizations (such as `-O2` in C) are allowed.

## Scoring

- I will time your code on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel i7-3770S processor) with different size of testcases. Specifically, I will generate some testcases with N = floor(2<sup>x/5</sup>) where x is a positive integer.
  Your score will be the x value of the smallest testcase that your program uses more than 10 seconds or 1 GiB of memory, or doesn't give a correct answer.

  - The answer with highest score wins. If two answers get the same score, the earlier answer wins.
- All programs will be judged by the same set of testcases.
- Feel free to post your own scorings. Explanations of your algorithm are encouraged.

## Bonus

[This](https://tio.run/##lVZbr9pGEH7Gv2KaKsg@NpRL1arcnnjj0ojXxIp8fAEnaxvZ5pxIR/z10m9m19gkbaUiYdYz33xz3V3C83lwDMPb7ec0D9UlimkRVnWUFiurlQTqWJRpfcpWlhUWeVVTmte029OSpiP@TOdWVZeXsKaqUC9xSW9WTxX5keRRXbKPu70/t3oGFBbZM71Ri3iZC2MwpytF50dwGeTHGGgGKI/OjCmPBsPCeutRfZhbXZevNmtST6y@OBxPr4zrS5lLNKlPriy@@DSQhZ1CAuAvNHkU4TvWYri7wokEHwbKbr190H72jtVjR8hg5KM2byOPRleY9eotXusDHiN@Rfj1wXU7GBKRP1QQ7dklp9MLLnVBCUQf@/73CZFJB85Sf/gCG@TsQYX6zBvb8BSHXzv2gbZ/1j9phyaxWefQaokl6xuepChJ@wbPeI5Gua6uZ09ccw6JzeFv/eFZOFwuCJSN0B8GnJLQ9dIEdLREmk4nBWmmVooV47kaiyWlugP11nUfMY3eofurQQvu9ZSqmGxw/SS17/d1OcT4gB6PdbwedQTKgafDYHD3xJ1jc@2kaZp4ga1OKVZVTE1YDRF7bZpq6iXTykF2cXBPLfIefRO@SGhBZcMhJBlMRFXKaM6NBiH8S4oZvyA39pUZuIStWsFVnt001T1F0f04o6K4Puw8OQBkYPZ6yjZeu9GfaG32iOwiTn7eOQayb6AeoLBZjsXvCv1d0G@jH8ZwhClETfZmGGVHy8RAd9/ea/zILmr5eRdivx0MbO83WZhib02xD6bYreWOC87qQ1twSaGMK6j4ONhxiT2MdTulcYXJX9Gm6R373@lisx7pLkjMHJ26oZARiau28O2ACeOiZTx8x5jDXcOYt4zlPzKa7cekL8Bt6Il0Fo7pbKcAa6EQ3Ba4cojjYs2BKpGhNuL0Ce/BvD1s1zykNowHWLLa3mAJDJfRBot5k7MVo3Yz90eCznWc69O@cyOFp7LIH@6oCtdFHGRdUVpkQZ6ecWm9FGlkJtOx3vS1gfHc8C0TBnliv3sfvY/eedSHtL/hcLicez5fUOsa3l55lv5zCg2RUky0Rt6p48kU8sFl6QO5qoOy5vGro9lMJzGbndLj6TO6UKhLnRb551AV4dfZLC9ebY7kXMKjYf6UgzsZ6lQ4A3hwGCTscR79T@4HbHQpAwYtouLyrOIVRWnCtw/TDnTonEgbT0JVjP8DUSVhMXoYFpe8tjkkHAtyVAVpLkUnfEwLoLz9QVNrhN02xmNMkxFN8Jzg/wRNJ3@FiQqO1W3w5/Q2QIjL0HXHv/4N) is my C++ program, it scores **108**. You can verify the SHA-256 digest `9a87fa183bad1e3a83d2df326682598796a216b3a4262c32f71dfb06df12935d` by the whole code segment (without footer) in the link.

The algorithm combines binary search and Knuth's optimization to find the correct penalty of each plant to get the desired number. The complexity is O(N log N log A[N-1]). I was surprised that the program got a higher score than the [O(N log A[N−1]) solution by Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149780/75905). It's probably due to the fact that the log case in Knuth's optimization won't usually occur.

Note that this challenge is the same as [IOI 2000 Post Office](http://www.ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi00/contest/day2/post/post.pdf). The original constraints are N <= 300 and K <= 30, though.

Comment: `2^^(x/5)` : what is the meaning ? can you just provide an upper bound for N ?

Comment: @Setop For example, if your program can deal with `N=21( = floor(2^(22/5)) )` in 10 seconds, but cannot deal with `N=24( = floor(2^(23/5)) )`, then 23 will be the score. I didn't use an upper bound, since the differences between different algorithms are too great. For example, if I set N <= 40, there will be little difference between `O(KN^2)` and `O(KN^3)`, however `O(2^N)` will not even finish in resonable time.

Comment: This is pretty much what I do for a living, and I can tell you this much: This is not the way we design the electrical grid!

Comment: [Random test generator](https://tio.run/##PU7LjsIwDDzjr7A42aiKWjiDxJlPQByibQCLxI2SXCq0395N2IrT2B7PI87lOelhWSTEKRVMVscpwLrlOQOIRjyil1wo2EiipWuEyWUUNcnZ0Ys6YpOjl0LMDFoFVXbtb/AjZa6mD7eehhvKHb3TahQZT0fco/PZ4dD3/U4BXvXxv4VpUONo6FAZYmrz9lL592@H5w9u0dynFGxBenUIm1xru5FWg2xD9I4@@fRtws2OgZGXpaX@AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Excellent challenge, excellent scoring system. Well done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), score = 104

This is an implementation of the algorithm noted by [Grønlund et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07204) at the end of §3.3.1, though I had to follow a long citation chain and fill in some missing details.  It runs in *O*(*N* log *A*[*N* − 1]) time.

Compile with `rustc -O`. Input format is `K` on the first line, followed by the entries of `A`, one entry per line, all on stdin.

(Note: I’m submitting this an hour after the bounty deadline, but I expect the [last version I submitted before the bounty deadline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/149780/16), which ran in *O*(*N* log *N* log *A*[*N* − 1]) time, to score about 94.)

```rust
use std::cmp::min;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::iter::{once, Cloned};
use std::num::Wrapping;
use std::ops::Range;
use std::slice;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::u64;

type Cost = u64;
const INF: Cost = u64::MAX;

trait ColsTrait<Col>: Clone {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Col>;
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter;
    fn slice(&self, range: Range<usize>) -> Self;
}

impl<'a, Col: Clone> ColsTrait<Col> for &'a [Col] {
    type Iter = Cloned<slice::Iter<'a, Col>>;
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        (*self).len()
    }
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        (*self).iter().cloned()
    }
    fn slice(&self, range: Range<usize>) -> Self {
        unsafe { self.get_unchecked(range) }
    }
}

impl ColsTrait<usize> for Range<usize> {
    type Iter = Range<usize>;
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.end - self.start
    }
    fn iter(&self) -> Range<usize> {
        self.clone()
    }
    fn slice(&self, range: Range<usize>) -> Self {
        Range {
            start: self.start + range.start,
            end: self.start + range.end,
        }
    }
}

fn smawk<Col: Copy, Cols: ColsTrait<Col>, Key: Ord, F: Copy + Fn(usize, Col) -> Key>(
    n: usize,
    shift: u32,
    cols: Cols,
    f: F,
) -> Vec<usize> {
    if n == 0 {
        Vec::new()
    } else if cols.len() > n {
        let mut s = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        let mut sk = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for (jk, j) in cols.iter().enumerate() {
            while match s.last() {
                Some(&l) => f(!(!(s.len() - 1) << shift), j) <= f(!(!(s.len() - 1) << shift), l),
                None => false,
            } {
                s.pop();
                sk.pop();
            }
            if s.len() < n {
                s.push(j);
                sk.push(jk);
            }
        }
        smawk1(
            n,
            shift,
            cols,
            f,
            smawk(n / 2, shift + 1, &s[..], f)
                .into_iter()
                .map(|h| unsafe { *sk.get_unchecked(h) }),
        )
    } else {
        smawk1(
            n,
            shift,
            cols.clone(),
            f,
            smawk(n / 2, shift + 1, cols, f).into_iter(),
        )
    }
}

fn smawk1<
    Col: Copy,
    Cols: ColsTrait<Col>,
    Key: Ord,
    F: Fn(usize, Col) -> Key,
    Iter: Iterator<Item = usize>,
>(
    n: usize,
    shift: u32,
    cols: Cols,
    f: F,
    iter: Iter,
) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut out = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut range = 0..0;
    for (i, k) in iter.enumerate() {
        range.end = k + 1;
        out.push(
            range
                .clone()
                .zip(cols.slice(range.clone()).iter())
                .min_by_key(|&(_, col)| f(!(!(2 * i) << shift), col))
                .unwrap()
                .0,
        );
        out.push(k);
        range.start = k;
    }
    if n % 2 == 1 {
        range.end = cols.len();
        out.push(
            range
                .clone()
                .zip(cols.slice(range.clone()).iter())
                .min_by_key(|&(_, col)| f(!(!(n - 1) << shift), col))
                .unwrap()
                .0,
        );
    }
    out
}

fn solve(k: usize, a: &[Cost]) -> Cost {
    if k >= a.len() {
        return 0;
    }
    let sa = once(Wrapping(0))
        .chain(a.iter().scan(Wrapping(0), |s, &x| {
            *s += Wrapping(x);
            Some(*s)
        }))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let c = |i: usize, j: usize| {
        let h = (i - j) / 2;
        unsafe {
            (sa.get_unchecked(i) - sa.get_unchecked(i - h) - sa.get_unchecked(j + h)
                + sa.get_unchecked(j))
                .0
        }
    };
    let cost1 = c(a.len(), 0);
    if k == 1 {
        return cost1;
    }
    let cost2 = (1..a.len()).map(|j| c(j, 0) + c(a.len(), j)).min().unwrap();
    let mut low = 0;
    let mut high = cost1 - cost2;
    let mut ret = INF;
    while low <= high {
        let penalty = low + (high - low) / 2;
        let mut out = vec![(INF, 0); a.len() + 1];
        out[0] = (0, 0);
        let mut begin = 0;
        let mut chunk = 1;
        loop {
            let r = min(a.len() + 1 - begin, 2 * chunk);
            let edge = begin + chunk;
            let (out0, out1) = out.split_at_mut(edge);
            let f = |i: usize, j: usize| {
                let h = (edge + i - j) / 2;
                let &(cost, count) = unsafe { out0.get_unchecked(j) };
                (
                    cost.saturating_add(
                        unsafe {
                            sa.get_unchecked(edge + i) - sa.get_unchecked(edge + i - h)
                                - sa.get_unchecked(j + h)
                                + sa.get_unchecked(j)
                        }.0 + penalty,
                    ),
                    count + 1,
                )
            };
            for ((i, j), o) in smawk(r - chunk, 0, begin..edge, &f)
                .into_iter()
                .enumerate()
                .zip(out1.iter_mut())
            {
                *o = min(f(i, begin + j), *o);
            }
            let x = unsafe { out1.get_unchecked(r - 1 - chunk) };
            if let Some(j) = (edge..begin + r - 1).find(|&j| &f(r - 1 - chunk, j) <= x) {
                begin = j;
                chunk = 1;
            } else if r == a.len() + 1 - begin {
                break;
            } else {
                chunk *= 2;
            }
        }
        let &(cost, count) = unsafe { out.get_unchecked(a.len()) };
        if count > k {
            low = penalty + 1;
        } else {
            ret = cost.wrapping_sub(k as Cost * penalty);
            if count == k {
                return ret;
            }
            high = penalty - 1;
        }
    }
    ret
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();
    let k = lines.next().unwrap().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
    let a = lines
        .map(|s| s.unwrap().parse().unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let start = Instant::now();
    let cost = solve(k, &a);
    let time = start.elapsed();
    println!(
        "cost: {}\ntime: {}.{:09} sec",
        cost,
        time.as_secs(),
        time.subsec_nanos()
    );
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vhtb9s2EP7uX3EtsFRyFM3OimJTbANbgQLFsBZoh21AFhisTMeyZUowpTpp7L@@7O4oydSLk2zrl7lAKvGOx3t97qhNrrP7@1xL0NksCMJ1GgTrSF30qqUoCYI7LeO5Bz/l8w9SzPY2NZMbpCcqlB68jhMla2SVr4Pg941I00hdW@tJqoPgg1DX0lrUcRTa71m0lkHwVulMqMxaz1@9vOj1sttUwutEZzAGXgkT5IS3794E1nIQ/PLjH8S9EVGG67H@lZ5G@DQJjMJw1wP8sby3ZA7/FVmyGeHDGuUQ8wUzzRXEUjkn5A8XziaQ6@iLrGjkDYv4ER/QAFysONhGw@LBhhwQAPthxJIm1b6L3r7Xi9ZpPHohPNKg0HbSMALmyQZOXgi4xLerpi2kPAdlxAcbZUqJkweNKkTRz@kzyScul1f3j1rcsZ15XT9khZqCnuwYS3CutJijokC7/GuZTXMVLmS4QvEswi3k70tnWs4zYtl99jkdHrTJT/QYKyTVDM7MI6bwJnvQcx06VILYY1/DYUy33vkEUi2w1IRTI868eTVmNKmTFdcPjJbPSc@12K5GJoGT9JYzTweNLPbgZ3kbwPvNzIM3hhFlv1EO28J72B7kmjgsXgXG6eZYvYjmaET@3bl5D6szzPs8gDdej0X8JsO6m6M5KBiPYWA5BpkQvOS2dDrIGNEHOUmwqQOY4LbDjlhmsM4z0JgwvHsbZYtpKFIRRtmto9yLNuvqcV5KT2e58mDpQqTM8UUdSQRXwinMjEZIt4solrAWWbgA1FborMVCv4/JGhMIHTvGMnCe4b/StDMYujAaGbe6fPho/AhP7HqtE94RvJJ0ge6rk/cdCmk/TVLHsr4irLoo@9obBqdUbVSLjCU91wtneUQ@01ZHjzg8cUIPnRqfqhvHPqkvhVUuVqFt7CGxjoJv4dwzArAChh6c6Evfv/Jg7rbU9iOVJVOTDm3iWqTObrE7oGQfzayD5AIB0gpbLdnvvoLBJXL9K8PZY0B942BlS1cbZIYjXjtATfnahhumVJDDbwg7nXhjqN2DgcERr/cfMIlTtxJ@DKNKyEjy7GHMKBkZlpF14PuDomcRkkQerBhI6MgjCFIhOm5fUSgOJYHHm0KpBZA3tPPP7lo1wpcodTg7TAsz5xXc5ZTQlc@Rmn66na7krbM7caacIO6uQKVz6ENUwyOidkjJ1RbH0S61BlZydZhsQ4PVH8lJF1Zn5m7yDZxTRxke8eqhifwfXKtaUP8VXGuchUaXBZzEn6WzKgsIRAAnlzTGX3FB8EBftesVTMYgCrC3XCyzfKNgYJ9A9aAF@pxuKE55E3EGlv5@uBCRckTZV3UolM3pwQ5x6ORm1@gpfQ2nY6gYbxqtg7trXx/O2dfOTOJYhlkQjKjWp5OJYxVwiPruosoXy@Jp1xg3FsjmRBgdbM8Inhetubimj6NFA/0jauLtVVxcdFKWCAaLdnRPOzi70mPQHBAtgzG8QyoMp4iqB4PCHxzuZi2ZQPOuZrBp8ZwcM/T9QphrWuFyh/KXJBlVtk5aEgMmgFslcB1K42RLQFpfXETXC65kUvzMnNpAYEnYgNdRs2xmMpKFkxTvrgczlUrE2S1uIZ5TcJjnjN4a0a33gs8yfHbp4DHssqoqELavauByObgirwwOnrVlfZLX2BQqK21SuMgVDapWG4iTJG1kF3HTXWnNlVTpgAawaA8IoFlUo0xoo5xxrzJKnBq2NpeDVqD6@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@IzoIywifUBn41GGL2ORavruaujpBjEpVs8OfeU5yQrgbv@n4i/v@OTfBYMf9qBl@PyAnJzA1Rux@kJPkUfb93Nex3TC9akSKtEFuOHx@/v7YW/QO@@97L3qff9XOI/Ftb4/e/83)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), pretest score = 73

Compile with `rustc -O`.  Input format is `K` on the first line, followed by the entries of `A`, one entry per line, all on stdin.

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::iter::once;
use std::num::Wrapping;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::u64;

type Cost = u64;
const INF: Cost = u64::MAX;

fn smawk<Col: Clone, Key: Ord, F: Clone + Fn(usize, &Col) -> Key>(
    n: usize,
    shift: u32,
    cols: &[Col],
    f: F,
) -> Vec<usize> {
    if n == 0 {
        Vec::new()
    } else if cols.len() > n {
        let mut s = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        let mut sk = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for (jk, j) in cols.iter().enumerate() {
            while match s.last() {
                Some(l) => f(!(!(s.len() - 1) << shift), j) <= f(!(!(s.len() - 1) << shift), l),
                None => false,
            } {
                s.pop();
                sk.pop();
            }
            if s.len() < n {
                s.push(j.clone());
                sk.push(jk);
            }
        }
        smawk1(
            n,
            shift,
            cols,
            f.clone(),
            smawk(n / 2, shift + 1, &s, f)
                .into_iter()
                .map(|h| unsafe { *sk.get_unchecked(h) }),
        )
    } else {
        smawk1(
            n,
            shift,
            cols,
            f.clone(),
            smawk(n / 2, shift + 1, &cols, f).into_iter(),
        )
    }
}

fn smawk1<Col: Clone, Key: Ord, F: Clone + Fn(usize, &Col) -> Key, Iter: Iterator<Item = usize>>(
    n: usize,
    shift: u32,
    cols: &[Col],
    f: F,
    iter: Iter,
) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut out = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut range = 0..0;
    for (i, k) in iter.enumerate() {
        range.end = k + 1;
        out.push(
            range
                .clone()
                .zip(unsafe { cols.get_unchecked(range.clone()) })
                .min_by_key(|&(_, col)| f(!(!(2 * i) << shift), col))
                .unwrap()
                .0,
        );
        out.push(k);
        range.start = k;
    }
    if n % 2 == 1 {
        range.end = cols.len();
        out.push(
            range
                .clone()
                .zip(unsafe { cols.get_unchecked(range.clone()) })
                .min_by_key(|&(_, col)| f(!(!(n - 1) << shift), col))
                .unwrap()
                .0,
        );
    }
    out
}

fn solve(k: usize, a: &[Cost]) -> Cost {
    let mut cost = vec![INF; a.len() + 1 - k];
    let sa = once(Wrapping(0))
        .chain(a.iter().scan(Wrapping(0), |s, &x| {
            *s += Wrapping(x);
            Some(*s)
        }))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    cost[0] = 0;
    let cols = (0..a.len() + 1 - k).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    for m in 0..k {
        cost = {
            let f = |i: usize, &j: &usize| {
                if i + 1 >= j {
                    let h = (i + 1 - j) / 2;
                    unsafe {
                        cost.get_unchecked(j).saturating_add(
                            (sa.get_unchecked(i + m + 1) - sa.get_unchecked(i + m + 1 - h)
                                - sa.get_unchecked(j + m + h)
                                + sa.get_unchecked(j + m))
                                .0,
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    INF
                }
            };
            smawk(a.len() + 1 - k, 0, &cols, &f)
                .into_iter()
                .enumerate()
                .map(|(i, j)| f(i, &j))
                .collect()
        };
    }
    cost[a.len() - k]
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();
    let k = lines.next().unwrap().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
    let a = lines
        .map(|s| s.unwrap().parse().unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let start = Instant::now();
    let cost = solve(k, &a);
    let time = start.elapsed();
    println!(
        "cost: {}\ntime: {}.{:09} sec",
        cost,
        time.as_secs(),
        time.subsec_nanos()
    );
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vd7a@NGEP9fn2JyULNKFNVOj6OVH9AeBMLRO2ihLaTB7MmrSJa0Mt7VOTlbX73p7EqyVpaUXB9QugYjzWtndmZ@s9rmQj495YKBkCvPizLP2wuWBA78kAc/MboqplbDlWzreRn3mUHkeep5v27pZhPxe4Muo5R53g0XknJp0PM3r6eWJR83DN5mQsIcNMXPUBJu3l97Btnzfvz@N5QOOIiU7uLZ2yxBfpJx5sA79ujBh@3KgeuKBhdwzUkuos/IHqGsDZcLJbcgFuDiHpRM/SbCKJBI@eaqfPezRHgwukW9u5ISeHDtWNrIL8yfad0F7DUvCoDDfA7j6l0tFMLzYDtia1IBLMGoUVKZdhPGiQ0LVGs0EiYhzSUIjFdr7yIZLn26oX4kHwm3p13R@GXZINsCWccOrG2IeLm9Sh6xXYb5YlsqGfrS@KHWLowSBimVfgjoLRWyI6LWz1nKCJ7sfAEBOcNfHdklTGyYzcpztfXes/kLMontdDZ4rzKprFM8vTa76PFHuJtsQ4zgj4y4j1O03jA3tWuzVmIM67kIydr1VYERe2AfLRMPbtU86TKekJYcbwepz6ZNUglsU4LaoRNdZZ5w@BqunNIQ9sQEm0E4ENgd192Iy2xZVkaXmdINOYQHyLmgAYM9nGOo90wuc@6HzI/ZioQ2FIYLrbrf/@dBawsYtxlmx1mraPBl8ncBxoEbhY36n8psO8OHVGGYhox/BD@6TI/Gh@CoRocsl8/DQy24pfwe2wzGrjsuORo0IgdijRlqywGw0KrIW6F6rI66KXvcvmyGVoK0Qre@qmR2GZ@jDTkWnQavdtWVDtQdiRXYU7sRX358XMbskRxGZOkoM/ahQqMrOIeohUOK22Ml5zscbH0ujo066gnfhILSWxyDW5WaeGo1iKCHyFdwpQbJZOCEm9nxfztm3oH7f@GYy4PDA6j7Nks@MRLXrQW07CEh73Sj6LtEu0X88nrxiflnt3jfmAKtJgBWMnoc3zWNIigKqvsOqS84ZGwE4PohjTih9WwVPuWmpAMHxJ/Rw@FksJwLuJjDUfDhZG7oCXsumn2K1p5ZkjBfet5MgcASwaVSV3Hdju9UTzcRqLQihWCbn4RpD1tSSJAqEECt2PC9Orl2MGqXAKmH6JiD0RqToJ8PPSMViz7STizmsO7h10ZD5XdUuYuXCYT3aa9wXcO9zNrvk9peY7aozBHbMANLulqRQW21iKAnBpRjqXJOXWqGucgM7WdNq9VjYV1Z@ALtiwFt@2VVs8FOV7920aF2xr25sMGs500U055hflKrDoyP43z0l@8xxhQbuOSosbfWuBWp6u3DqKpZDBOFCUi6@ejxlhvfVfCUKoCwDQTCbyBsrDmoLy39TE4GcxJxplpWM90k82NEFk00JdVHgCa6nD2gV0cMbR42dCuYQWiUaa1stY9BHPC@O6j/JRhURlhOuurTD7@Isp3Jr1CkAm48b2ow1VejDh5tuCyhG4HVXPE3W0xzws@aVn2lbHmwL37n@nMTn9y9N/6uAMH8V04LuJo3JepSsUQZYV4INV3kH5G@5JRnoko2bl88PU2ssXVlvbbeWN/@4QcJvRdPlx/@BA)

Comment: You've got a pretest score `61`, but that's because overflow of `u32`. Maybe you can change to 64-bit integer type?

Comment: @ColeraSu Does it do better if I just change `type Cost = u32` to `type Cost = u64`?

Comment: Yes. You got `63`.

Comment: Wow, I had never thought of SMAWK algorithm. Nice job, you got `73`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Impressive! The algorithm is brilliant, the programming language - not so much.

Comment: @ngn What do you have against Rust? :-(

Comment: @AndersKaseorg My only experience with Rust is this post, a few examples and a presentation on YouTube. First impressions: too verbose, imposes unnecessary abstractions, static typing only gets in the way. To be fair, Rust binaries are surprisingly fast despite their size, and I find rustc's error messages helpful. I'm actually trying to rewrite your code in C (not my favourite language either - I'm an APL/J/k fan) to see if it's any faster and I'll post as non-competing it if I'm successful.

Comment: @ngn Wow, this was definitely not intended to be an introduction to Rust. Perhaps you don’t realize how little these abstractions actually cost (and that they are not “imposed”), but you’ll find that out soon enough. To make your comparison fair, I’ve gone and turned off bounds checking on the vector accesses. As for binary size, did you try `strip`?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Strip takes it from a few MB down to hundreds of kB. For comparison, my binary is a little more than 3 kB but I did go out of my way to get rid of libc.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg The current Rust source doesn't compile (or am I doing something wrong?), so I tested against the old source. The C translation I posted is about twice as fast.

Comment: @ngn It compiles fine at the TIO link. Perhaps your rustc version is too old?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg you guessed correctly, mine: 1.14.0, tio: 1.21.0

Comment: @AndersKaseorg ok, this is better - only ~50% slower than C

Comment: @ColeraSu Here’s a third algorithm that’s even faster!

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Sorry, SMAWK (autocorrect). I'd like to use it as a base for a solution, but as you used it first, I was asking if you'd object / feel like I was encroaching on your answer. It wouldn't be a literal translation of your solution (unlike one of the C ones).

Comment: @Οurous The degree of originality in your answer depends on the degree of originality in your answer, I guess?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I'll get started then, thanks.

Comment: Congratulations on winning the first bounty!

Answer (score 6):

## C, score = 56

content of `a.c`:

```
typedef void V;typedef char C;typedef long L;typedef unsigned long U;
#define R return
#define W while
#define S static
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#define h1(f,x    )({L r;asm volatile("syscall":"=a"(r):"0"(SYS_##f),"D"(x)              :"cc","rcx","r11","memory");r;})
#define h3(f,x,y,z)({L r;asm volatile("syscall":"=a"(r):"0"(SYS_##f),"D"(x),"S"(y),"d"(z):"cc","rcx","r11","memory");r;})
#define read(a...) h3(read ,a)
#define write(a...)h3(write,a)
#define exit(a...) h1(exit ,a)
S V P(U x){C s[32],*p=s+32;*--p='\n';do{*--p='0'+x%10;x/=10;}W(x);write(1,p,s+32-p);}
S V mc(V*x,V*y,L n){C*p=x,*q=y;for(L i=0;i<n;i++)p[i]=q[i];}
#define min(x,y)({typeof(x)_x=(x),_y=(y);_x+(_y-_x)*(_y<_x);})
#define t(x,i,j)x[(i)*(n+n-(i)+1)/2+(j)] //triangle indexing
#define x(i,j)t(x,i,j)
#define y(i,j)t(y,i,j)
#define z(i,j)t(z,i,j)
#define N 4096 //max
L n;U ka[N+1],c[N],x[N*(N+1)/2],y[N*(N+1)/2],z[N*(N+1)/2];
V _start(){
 C s[1<<20];L r=0;U v=0;
 W(0<(r=read(0,s,sizeof(s))))for(L i=0;i<r;i++)if('0'<=s[i]&&s[i]<='9'){v=s[i]-'0'+10*v;}else{ka[n++]=v;v=0;}
 n--;U k=*ka,*a=ka+1;
 for(L i=n-1;i>=0;i--)for(L j=i-1;j>=0;j--)x(j,i)=x(j+1,i)-a[j]+a[i];
 for(L i=0;i<n;i++)for(L j=i+1;j<n;j++)y(i,j)=y(i,j-1)+a[j]-a[i];
 for(L i=n-1;i>=0;i--)for(L j=i+1;j<n;j++){
  U v=~0ul,*p=&x(i,i),*q=&y(i,j);for(L l=i;l<j;l++){v=min(v,*p+++*q);q+=n-l;} //min(v,x(i,l)+y(l,j));
  z(i,j)=v;}
 mc(c,z,8*n);
 for(L m=1;m<k;m++)for(L j=n-1;j>=m;j--){
  U v=~0ul,*p=&z(j,j);for(L i=j-1;i>=m-1;i--){v=min(v,c[i]+*p);p-=n-i;} //min(v,c[i]+z(i+1,j))
  c[j]=v;}
 P(c[n-1]);exit(0);}
```

shell script to compile and test the above:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
clang -O3 -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-unwind-tables -fno-unroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -oa a.c
strip -R.comment -R'.note*' a;stat -c'size:%s' a
t(){ r="$(echo "$1"|./a)";if [ "$r" != "$2" ];then echo "in:$1, expected:$2, actual:$r";fi;} #func tests
t '1 0 2 4 6 8' 12
t '3 0 1 10 11 20 21 22 30 32' 23
t '5 0 1 3 6 8 11 14' 3
t '6 0 1 3 6 8 14 15 18 29 30 38 41 45 46 49 58 66 72 83 84' 49
t '2 0 7 9' 2
for n in 1176 1351 1552 1782 2048;do #perf test
 echo "n:$n";a=0 inp="$((2*n/3))" RANDOM=1;for i in `seq $n`;do inp="$inp $a";a=$((a+=RANDOM%1000));done
 ulimit -t10 -v1048576;time ./a<<<"$inp"
done
```

<s>n=776 takes 6.2s, n=891 takes 12s</s>

<s>n=1176 takes 5.9s, n=1351 takes a little over 10s</s>

n=1351 takes 8.7s, n=1552 takes more than 10s
(with k=2*n/3) on my `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2375M CPU @ 1.50GHz`

Comment: I suppose this isn't code-golf?

Comment: @user202729 It's how I normally write C code - [incunabulum](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Incunabulum)-style.

Comment: @ngn I assume you then also normally do not use any kind of syntax highlighting?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I do, actually. I've customised my `syntax/c.vim`.

Comment: It doesn't work with `K = 2, A = [0, 7, 9]`. It outputs `7` instead of `2`.

Comment: @ColeraSu Thanks. Fixed (it was an off-by-one error) and added to tests.

Comment: I'm most impressed by the fact that you can read that. Wow. Sans comments, too.

Comment: @cole This is just regular C, only denser. If you are familiar with the language, you should be able to read it without much difficulty, albeit several times slower, as one line here contains information most C programmers would spread over 5-10 lines (what a waste!). I wrote comments only for the trickiest bits.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, score = 53

The solution I had said in the comment. `O(n²×k)`. (now I deleted it because it is no longer necessary) Probably can be reduced to `O(n×k)`.

The input is pretty flexible, on the first line, the first number is `k`, the other numbers are items of array `a`, but if it encounters any close-parentheses it stops reading input. So input like `K = 1, A = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] : 12` is accepted.

```
// https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149029/build-an-electrical-grid

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>

bool read(std::istream& str, int& x) {

    char ch;

    do {
        if (str >> x) return true;
        if (str.eof()) return false;
        str.clear(); // otherwise it's probably int parse error
    } while (str >> ch && ch != ']' && ch != ')' && ch != '}');
    // ignore 1 character, but treat any close parentheses as end of input

    // cannot read anything now
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int k; std::vector<int> a;

    //{ Read input
    std::string st; std::getline(std::cin, st);
    std::stringstream sst (st);

    read(sst, k);

    int x;
    while (read(sst, x)) a.push_back(x);
    //}

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> dp (a.size(), std::vector<int>(k));
    // dp[n][k] = min distance you can get for cities [n..a.size()-1]
    // and [k+1] power plants, and city [n] has a power plant.

    // sum_array[x] = sum of coordinates of cities [x..a.size()-1]
    std::vector<int> sum_array (a.size()+1);
    sum_array.back() = 0;
    for (int n = a.size(); n --> 0;)
        sum_array[n] = sum_array[n+1] + a[n];

    for (int n = a.size(); n --> 0;) {
        for (int k1 = k; k1 --> 0;) {
            if (k1 == 0) {
                int nWire = a.size() - 1 - n;
                dp[n][k1] = sum_array[n+1] - nWire * a[n];
            } else {
            // unindent because my screen width is limited

dp[n][k1] = INT_MAX / 2; // avoid stupid overflow error (in case of -ftrapv)

// let [n1] be the next position for a power plant
int first_connect_right = n; // < lengthy variable name kills screen width
// ^ lengthy comment kills screen width

for (int n1 = n + 1; n1 < (int)a.size(); ++n1) {

    while (a[first_connect_right]-a[n] < a[n1]-a[first_connect_right]) ++first_connect_right;

    int nRightWire = n1 - first_connect_right, nLeftWire = first_connect_right - 1 - n;
    dp[n][k1] = std::min(dp[n][k1],
        a[n1]*nRightWire-(sum_array[first_connect_right]-sum_array[n1]) +
        (sum_array[n+1]-sum_array[first_connect_right])-a[n]*nLeftWire +
        dp[n1][k1-1]
    );

}

            }

        }
    }

    int ans = INT_MAX;
    for (int n = a.size()+1-k; n --> 0;) {
        ans = std::min(ans, dp[n].back() + a[n]*n-sum_array[0]+sum_array[n]);
    }

    std::cout << ans << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVnZbhzJEXznV7RhYEWuSKruYyUL8KPh48EwYAMyLYyGTXLAYQ89M9Thhb59HRHZPLQi7F1AwaquIysrMzKzZnl7e3K5XP7yy6tXw9V@f7v76dWr5eZ8vNysL053@8Xyevy8vFpMl@PpcnPz6t93426/2ky7Vz51F/qrD3er9fnJYjoZ1@Nyv10tF@uTy@3q/ODgt6tpub47H4c3q81uvx0XN2@f9H3E6M32aQ/GrKbLb3q@n7Zcr25W@93bg4MPm816wOfzw93@/KefVjb2hwF4PKym/Q/D56Ph54ODAf/hAFv889pa5xv0D/N/q4sBC2yHt285fjvu77bTsN/eja9/PeR03FwcHj2MuVisd08GccByPS62h0evB@hys78at59Wu3FY7V/shtvt5sPiw/oLJRtuF1v0j9vtZqv5X4dPV6v1@CDI8mr44Qf@@5vfDS/OXjxpHD1tfH1xZPtju9XltNmOg9dRF8v9CCV8uNsPVMp@WExfhuV6g02x9ThBtN24Gxa7YZzOh80FhLq92x/cr7VcTNNmL91y5v4K1zJMm0/6/u3pvx4c8EA3i9V0eDRrlR3Xrwfdit3yG3S9HRav73f4efgr17ZdTXkYa/ePv@e5l@N@vZpGu97lajpG93zgJ@Pt2geYCtV3NO9hdrHbHw/X910U67NNn7X9OOgzrnVxenu3u3r/ARZ/@PlBsV8PHjecD/Prg70dzm@Hw8XpbvWf8fDo@LuDH14fPd7T@e276ezd9dnwu@FmNQ3nMNvFtByHL5s76n3AoYeLDYx1tV/hit5Np6f3K5/4s/tVFri2d9cv/dlwu/k0bofb9WLa747Vj5lfMO9suML9Lp4OOH244d3dzfvFdrv48u4zJUGTVrDcbLbnq2mxx8ZsziJ8/l6E7@72YcFHRbz095d1/@1Uuj3Chs6@8KCHvJcJfffzXqN1cvIWY44enetB3mmW975JHbwcFuifr/n/rfnE9R@GXnuMhckCvx91zwAcBMl//enetKa/r@B/j1sOJ3DGk2F6/d3o2QT8Myc5mZf5cT7R02lfhxEu96vdcZd302o6h08PH8bl4g4jbr4Mu@V2HKfh0@p8fzWsdoNIcwQnP937D3/52/s///4fw6shiLEWHzerc1zt3S1g83HcXqw3n4ylqCaYJxaHXZxc7LeL249HBweYtIa9vpuw3odxAK0M0/gZ/LbZrRgkpOFvTFBscbHa7vbvl5tpggW9364ur/YQZ5IQb7DidLm/@jJ8XGxXYEwsubgZh@vVer375lzc/V8PoxGbbqiEZ8YdPJoE73mCvfjX/PuNeo8ejeTly8k/xIyZJBbvnhH37IT3gwUWPPvJ82OOsN4z/U/oaPorO2bDmWguz4w/HqY/jRf3o57T3TeW9o110U1BM4cPnccP1iPJf3yU4OTw0RafPfETU/U828NKh98a8cn/XudIqvvx8UyPC1FKTzHvaYbUPRPwgxc8Nr8ePOmgOhfT7tGs/wfDvPQn188zgq3woDY0j02h99RlVPPj9OSQ7uzlU3qaSe9p3FhuEIjfvNHqgBf/nF48hCkFU9Dh119@@SO29t0dD7/HH@9ij8eDL2z76urxEHrwx0OMvuPf6gP@bbEcD6kX/J2bx9fcE76WVNHTquO/jV@7rxnrOJcLAf8DfM7sDCFwj@hzFNRGCIEjYw8cUkrvhBaipHGJEFslNIoYogsCiRcgH1YJuTVsHqpXq9bIVivN6zQREyJEajxVoOAxZgoRU/WJx0uFna1z24Rkk6d1zUGk5EMhhEYhUuyerdR4vlQCz5dqppKgnoRv2XVKDeBRsncR2@YQPITI0flIKBQ@p1IFjatAoET15iQovnFeCZGLVQmRG6Qn5CpoCfOKczxm8S5UQuLlleC5UcFJsEqJ3TneVsyYV5pTZ9M9lJb0raWeCaV1AVVQeigAXC/1Ul3hBGiMRgKJKDw0zVupBTcIqIEiQf/coVYcEIbBqyZkKqSFLptJwWFIw3ExvRXH07aauUqrnTrDbVCRMMYEIXp0gtx59l5cEmQXBZSz16wh3ezFORe9jDBQa8AYzSgj9wQWJ1sN2ak/5qbxuA9aJrQkn3A1WX@VhXvXQq6Gc3vu77GzHwvQHIClcj7@cF2YKDouJsgBIEYTZp81rnQvb6lFvuC77BfYo7kPbk7Y5WMh2rkCvFP9CR3CxDuE3bai7/M6kYIJu5cfwjNmTPJEqEWuWCPtmNiDuSZvGhh5c7h@6R5Y6EpA2z9Bk2rz5ES4u2GUU6fopLeU53E5eLVLTsJapb/UivSRwSHcL8N/naHkyRCM4@A3hvCKIkyeWMxggGAAoWzalxglDzhG7FKqKARYRVYFblXEOja/OrkLMJHfQEPR@pMIBdcEQYRF54LVO@MpVzQOVh0N7XurRdiN5DCMbAXs0ncDdao/YymhyQkrbBoHyuW@5DOO77EUtUFfHNdxAZzfs91Thz70vWWtQzMCBsf/iLRgYaUdBWd6Ci6KH4AgIWLzaUb73uVXIDTdG5gm0D6BVd8xWgwNTNZuMRpSLwEXSSYGRtonMGk/Kl7rdHElMFfD0q1f3IsokrUf7ZzrBYjRhZl@SyQFAgv1QLepasOu9b05Gw@zFXb5JTDTngKJRqHFddoF3SwIU9N6MXvpDW7H@wdWyYvQ0NWPeyLCT6h3MKL4Atg6909GwyEVky8ZbQF7ppzwXvoxWKlL/9nLf4BF@sogZfXHpnXBmeR6qoG8hmOXpn4E82KxsXFegQK4TolJeoT50s5CSc6nGTkeqxf1F5OzGB8Ac9R3LMfviM46f3VN3yskVD8U6ISFsSvgeLqXCq7X@NJtfIdFM0y7WA2z7ILX4oVe947dpN8GGhaWqvM18LLmwbw4rjuzO4RfnQNa0b49NMkFf7F2L@QVkIoPQl/IZ5H8z5wA/E89wQugIqF4Ds7duxKJlqPmddk7sNOuI/xA44DUH7B6w8ZwBuxZ3xFNmV/5XMlzCI5KGCIcnkEepy7KRkCfmgfroz4iZpFfkAIonoL0XDKUPcRgSUKEomgPwJI0H2kb5aNbZ6HyBmRCkfwB5YXqLSWy/qK4Bey0txhBSzxv7Eo7gDUqdwqKzxFhh3ZEbNaW/onSD8yd/g3szGxgTJ5xDmRa7DvCmrAGWxfXq/Vg3uxHiNc9AWnvwMZ4BjJLTf10IEOdP2dP@8Pgon1zFf/w9pXRFlo2MclPI7fnejVYhlihcCdsSg5rslyx4r64Pnmf58Oyus8Kwta8rjgSQS@yrzbbAxIfyd3ASOrPUfeD67bkMyvRjK3IjoFFeqSda1zpth7@4D6wc9krU221YTgc10MKhpW8gnDtlccjustuOhTohEn6RFzQPr0p30hMkA275b/BN2H0xbAo6QU9Ur/JoQZQugyFGMLTiJZ/IfhU3h@M0bHCAKaqftwE5zMgJ0Pt55Fecj4DpuYh3mhe60XjLRtNCnQzZkPNQwCS/CByy9iT7UPkOogLqmJC7vTPBO@mHycQFe0faEk9rl3nAHHYOl18lUhLHAfHID/AvBWHieRBmrv2gblrPv1I46vyKgipOJugAMaZxAPxe7K4C1S@meg/@o7qivNo1sGQFROs1qtMQX5E@4M7OeYnicVFEcZsbcUNoOk1s0QQlqY2knbug6yXeSWwav3ixNup@EA7QpETmJelEoPmFwQkL@xO/eUB6VfI@YP0UJCpc52KPIHzKiO2sOleKm5c1RMU0IVJ@7NqqKqqUjdUXo6P4q3EOpB6Rx4l@RoTFWFjBQT2ztIDKhrptyGeUR7EC/sO9@B@iBvMoxlu6RfAJLn7bO8wL@kF6YHk6gjPKuxQCLBCc0joWaIhynO/jLihks1ZPkts6gd9q7@qUAP7ZVVxPqgAAzaek6ylUpF5EmtFlCeaj8SFfoasSXwClD6QBiRVmJiuohJ2yviWZzsFyyhPhhnEqKIzKg6wzKSfkD61HwhTBSvYrKhdPf0ik7i4DuyV9gwskpOVm6G3KhaZWRT2oP6o/D8jv6d@gaY3GFKaUeeGQc1Yu8YXxUdmc/G@LFZ/E3/BGuQntAryMKT2khcKlp5gltoXB6U/0tulFwikcyIttPFF9RZI2WnfbHk6sHat25SXwLnkr7k4xSVM8xoP7@iq0BFZhEn1GYKcL6rVkc84oeIXsEnu6hVHgcULrY4B9mztbuOSeIDZgfQLlF5rlR0DK/kaYU1vLZl@wHuCV3VhsPcEoO6vMUIRi8kLdpX@6O5q92Bt0FwVNukR6Sz9HUKHqnbWMw6wFb0AWT0D1GsNqnvlY3yPoH0U5/XCU5hm6Z0C4kZh11OD4wsL0ewZtKPzFcfASuy6H6DsEeylvAfKc@QLoPILXLLTswYKSvueZB9A6QG3HbywBpvHhFJYsrWVlxfGF81HQDRU/gP6i3pnCSl3valU1VNA2W1h4tqFqpMLy2ruj0SS9w1UXlCQ4GlfJmpCGDLPD7Yu2bBpPCxN43GDwiK@LQw7lAf@qX2jxYMS5/2RSOjNB3Em6rXHyT8LA3nQ64@XXEDyFtDOi4DT1A@H4bogfvorksdC3qF5e8Ok/UGAvH@gp58BG/NuJAfyb6C9NsGQmbeABZv2x8WTF4maRzekfEyzKQ834P6MLxoPBlI/LFLj@H5lKHsBbWStB57ivGpPbcAiPVZGNCILJGJRXgesQeNQ2EeheApYpA/4lY1HguX1XCZ/5JukzgnrZP4ErIYI10I@swmLztes7kSwzcxXGAWkV6RHhsig@B1hRXbWs9khaIf@DWxe7SaeL6B3rocqWXqG9KHqWQ5MlomgSUM/Y@b9g@UU98h2vGeoKXBdqov3ARTvVu9LEAa99lY@k2l8Skn9fMskQo/c30ORGgdFar2mdyRYp/JvGLlnfgYsrBsq/chQdgGtKw/DZdj6KNzor8BKe4MRq/6riEu8T2ZpOg8Sbad2F58hu8rkZ6QTXfKgzpCekGBlfU/Kc5he0D4q8ijJl7p4A6g8GKj6oWaYE79nvggQk50DgYd8gzJAdSXLAeY1QPFrJbHqe1f8qiA4xqVa5vsC0egZtXjFF6B4H2Ypu0YW7fWiCkfU/bAOVxsD9MQKe9I8q8MrX269sNPOER6UhzE60B8qFas32eR1/zig5MUBNR@nZdyn2Qf1I7GiHHArnY91OfsbX/OJQe/bwK5z8cVY48jAQr2jAJUfY7VIfqIbSW981lE7qI4EihcR7ZXn8llM@/B5TOOrfpMAqh6oHWWcF6puZjVOv2p8x8pCvRcxa6Aemguyf2DheYE16DvyqkSsek9B9efsfZovDnquDs6eraVnOGvuaifxGthG70dAvQ80PjRqHMTKhlXjm/LCBm8j36P8K4z3Qj2Eow4KwsY42IK9ixGLviNBFzKiCvX@hCiTsvrrvG4Lhr14wyY9RNM76ErvBMAkOVHXW39VnEESWPUwD5bUPtHqnsZ3qyZMvCdgl5ysT7hPomMRs94RgMobGgqBoPmgG/VX1RsN2YG@ZxIYMSiOAU3fDH/6SQAJZtdPA136QoIlfWN52ierVvsOYmV7ft9FNBc/APUeTDPUPRSLRyynNQ@j7Vcrr/weWBh3EDXl17Au8Vujw6vffutq1eIY/u2yE0Q9ydWS6V8HFcoPIZ3ep5EMRc1HFNH54Bfap9sPKUDFwdbt/Rfk4O3nj6x3NlS/@vmlkRb1HdfO3z7AljwfUPUWrFj64uss7byjTqf/walUDzB6OLVxwDwjfy5BPOD9YZBXP/yAdo2sS3Vk54N@ExbmQZ0P9YbiM2LSvKz3AqDe8XEc2YmeJzSu6T0MaaXiJbMk1vfAQv2BHvR7hn7vEQbxTuf7l8Yjkef6oeodvPMdV/N6Zr2KwyfJGen5Qr27AmNWG/ltEGbGd6hZ76RdDwTEWCQPCvaqdjE9JP6cReyq7zvL306EQNwX6QXzlY5CZ0bxD9LlQj/CNeqdiOE9a37X70YoluXnQP0CC8y0787ErQkL7azzR1a1s@y981lB46vJzR/ruB@05DS@289g6LUfxyyfRUt1G1D1L8wpZP1qVpK1cT08D8MAEUQq/YJeyA@gX/Eof06gXwMj@aG3@b7heJIP7KP9@S6r703@20kvXii@AFbmOx3lN/MwRE3VhfyZQvfDi1M7q/4gNq2DcK75EIf7UiB/9l8)

[Generate random test cases.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149029/build-an-electrical-grid?noredirect=1#comment365807_149029) (input `N` and optionally city range, `1000×N` by default)

Comment: If it happens to be able to solve some larger test case, I will change the necessary `int`s to `int64_t`s.

Comment: dp[runned_n,runned_k]=min{dp[runned_n-x,runned_k]+f[x,n]}, so direct dynamic programming is O(n^2*k). Maybe need to totally change way to reduce complexity?

Comment: @l4m2 Don't spoil the algorithm! (well, the bounty has not expired)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite know if your "spoil" mean "throw away" or "steal" or both. Can find both meaning. I don't quite know this word. (I've also thought bounty means bound)

Comment: @l4m2 Spoil = say the algorithm to those who want to discover it themselves (which is bad) (in this particular case). Of course there will be explanation later after the bounty has expired.

Comment: The random test generator doesn’t enforce A[0] = 0 like the question specifies.

Comment: Still pretty sure that I can get better score with algorithmic optimization. Need to try to be sure.

Comment: Well, out-timed (mostly because I'm lazy)

Comment: @user202729: Any ideas in the mean-time ? I don't see how the inner-loop could be avoided resp. replaced by code running in sub-linear time.

Comment: @politza AndersKaseorg's algorithm is much more sophiscated anyway, so reduce O(n^2 * k) to O(n * log(n) * k) won't help much. Although, I do have an idea now...

Comment: I may still be faster in practice, also simplicity has its own appeal.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, score = 23

I am sure this is not going to win this challenge, I just wanted to post a first (and very basic) answer to encourage other people to post their algorithms and improve mine. This code must be compiled as a console project that uses the [Combinatorics package](https://github.com/eoincampbell/combinatorics) from NuGet. The main method contains some calls to the `Build` method to test the proposed cases.

```
using Combinatorics.Collections;
using System;

namespace ElectricalGrid
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Build(1, new long[] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 }) == 12)
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            if (Build(3, new long[] { 0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 30, 32 }) == 23)
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            if (Build(5, new long[] { 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14 }) == 3)
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            if (Build(6, new long[] { 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 14, 15, 18, 29, 30, 38, 41, 45, 46, 49, 58, 66, 72, 83, 84 }) == 49)
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static long Build(int k, long[] a)
        {
            var combs = new Combinations<long>(a, k);
            var totalDist = long.MaxValue;
            foreach (var c in combs)
            {
                long tempDist = 0;
                foreach (var i in a)
                {
                    var dist = long.MaxValue;
                    foreach (var e in c)
                    {
                        var t = Math.Abs(i - e);
                        if (t < dist) dist = t;
                    }
                    tempDist += dist;
                }
                if (tempDist < totalDist) totalDist = tempDist;
            }
            return totalDist;
        }
    }
}
```

Really simple explanation: for each combination `c` of `k` elements from `a`, calculate the sum of the distances from each element of `a` to the nearest element in `c`, and return the combination with the least total distance.

One-liner version of the `Build` method (probably slower than the original, expanded version; this needs to add a reference to `System.Linq`):

```
static long Build(int k, long[] a)
{
    return new Combinations<long>(a, k).Min(c => a.Sum(i => c.Min(e => Math.Abs(i - e))));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++, score = 48

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
typedef long long ull;
typedef unsigned int uint;
uint A[1<<20];
ull S[1<<20];

double ky = 1;
struct point {
    ull dist;
    int n;
    inline point() {}
    inline point(ull dist, int n): dist(dist), n(n) {}
    inline double res() const{
        return dist + n * ky;
    }
    inline int operator<(const point& other) const {
        return res() < other.res();
    }
} V[1<<20];
inline ull f(int L, int R) {
    int m = L+R+1 >> 1;
    return (S[R]-S[m]) - A[m]*(R-m) +
           A[m]*(m-L) - (S[m]-S[L]);
}
int main() {
    int N, K, i, j, p;
    scanf ("%d%d", &N, &K);
    ull s = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
        scanf ("%u", A+i);
        S[i] = s += A[i];
    }
    double kyL = 0, kyH = 1e99;
    point cL, cR;
    for (int step=0; step++<50; ky = std::min(ky*2, (kyL+kyH)*.5)) {
        for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
            point tmp(f(0,i), 1);
            for (j=1; j<i; j++) {
            //printf("ky=%f [%d]=%d %I64d %f\n", ky, i, tmp.n, tmp.dist, tmp.res());
                point cmp = V[j];
                cmp.dist += f(j, i);
                cmp.n ++;
                if (cmp<tmp) tmp=cmp;
            }
            //printf("ky=%f [%d]=%d %I64d %f\n", ky, i, tmp.n, tmp.dist, tmp.res());
            V[i] = tmp;
        }
        if (V[N].n == K) {
_:          return! printf("%I64d", V[N].dist);
        }
        if (V[N].n > K) {
            kyL = ky;
            cL = V[N];
        } else {
            kyH = ky;
            cR = V[N];
        }
        //printf("ky=%f %d %I64d %f\n", ky, V[N].n, V[N].dist, V[N].res());
        //getch();
    }
    V[N].dist = (double)cL.dist / (cR.n-cL.n) * (K-cL.n) +
                (double)cR.dist / (cL.n-cR.n) * (K-cR.n) + .5;
    printf("%I64d", V[N].dist);
}
```

Usage input:
N K A[1] A[2] ... A[N]

Comment: If you increase the limit of `step` to 70, then your pretest score is 60.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score = 23

```ruby
->a,l{d=l.map{|x|l.map{|y|(x-y).abs}};[*0...l.size].combination(a).map{|r|r.map{|w|d[w]}.transpose.sum{|r|r.min}}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtNCoMwFISvkqWW@LAaraXYi4QsYlUQNEqiqDU5e/qoLmb4mB@9VLtvSx@9Je2PuuxhkNNhN3vBboMt2kOQlXHuxW8xAPRgum8j4DMOVafk3I0qkOG511afsNqar8LBrKUy02gaMMtw9Z1y7u9@Ii3PKY8puVOSUpJTUiAzVIZCTp5YYJ8iMxwxzBnOGOYZZjnyI8EbvgsmhP8B)

I don't think it's going to win, but I wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (ES6) (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), score = 10

New Algorithm, will explain if it actually works this time.

```javascript
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');

class Connection{
    constructor(left,index,length,right){
        if(typeof right === 'undefined'){
            this._distance = 0;
        } else {
            this._distance = typeof left === 'undefined' ? 0 :
                    Math.abs(right - left);
        }
        var half = Math.floor(length/2);
        if(length % 2 < 1){
            this._magnitude = half - Math.abs(index - half + 1);
        } else {
            var temp = index - half;
            this._magnitude = half - Math.abs(temp >= 0 ?temp:temp + 1);
        }
        this._value = this.distance * this.magnitude;
    }

    get distance(){return this._distance;};
    get magnitude(){return this._magnitude;};
    set magnitude(value){
        this._magnitude = value;
        this._value = this.distance * this.magnitude;
    };
    valueOf(){return this._value};
}

class Group{
	constructor(...connections){
        this._connections = connections;
		
		this._max = Math.max(...connections); //uses the ValueOf to get the highest Distance to the Left
	}
	get connections(){return this._connections;};
	get max(){return this._max;};
    cutLeft(index){

            for(let i=1,j=index-1;;i++){
                
                if(typeof this.connections[j] === 'undefined' || this.connections[j].magnitude <= i){
                    break;
                }
                this.connections[j].magnitude = i;
                j--;
            }

    }

    cutRight(index){

            for(let i=0,j=index;;i++){
                
                if(typeof this.connections[j] === 'undefined' || this.connections[j].magnitude <= i){
                    break;
                }
                this.connections[j].magnitude = i;
                j++;
            }

    }

    static of(...connections){
        return new Group(...connections.map((c,i)=>new Connection(c.distance,i,connections.length)));
    }

	split(){
        var index = this.connections.findIndex(c=>c.valueOf() == this.max);
        if(index < 0){
            return;
        }
        var length = this.connections.length;
        var magnitude = this.connections[index].magnitude;

        this.cutLeft(index);
        this.cutRight(index);
        this._max = Math.max(...this.connections);
	}

    center(){
        if(typeof this._center === 'undefined'){
            this._center = this.connections.reduce((a,b)=>a==0?b.valueOf():a.valueOf()+b.valueOf(),0);
        }
        return this._center;
    }

    valueOf(){return this._max;};
    toString(){
        var index = this.connections.findIndex(c=>c.valueOf() == this.max);
        var value = this.connections[index].magnitude;
        var ret = '';
        for(let i = 0;i<value;i++){
            ret += this.connections.map(c=>{return (i<c.magnitude)?c.distance:' ';}).reduce((a,b)=>a==''?b:a+'-'+b,'') + '\n';
        }
        return ret;
    };
}

function crunch(plants, cities){
	var found = [];
    var size = cities.length;
    cities = cities.map((city,i,arr)=> new Connection(city,i,size,arr[i+1])).slice(0,cities.length-1);
    var group = new Group(...cities);
    for(;plants>1;plants--){
    group.split();
    }
    console.log(`Wire Length Needed: ${group.center()}`);
}

function biggestGroup(groups){
	return groups.find(g => g[g.length-1].orig - g[0].orig);
}

function* range (start, end, limit) {
    while (start < end || typeof limit !== 'undefined' && limit-- > 0) {
        yield start
        start += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }
}

function* cities (score){
	let n = Math.floor(Math.pow(2,score/5));
	var start = 0;
	while (n-- > 0 && start <= (1000 * n)) {
		yield start;
        start += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }
}


if(typeof process.argv[3] === 'undefined'){
    crunch(1,[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 12");
    crunch(3,[0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 30, 32]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 23");
    crunch(5,[0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 3");
    crunch(6,[0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 14, 15, 18, 29, 30, 38, 41, 45, 46, 49, 58, 66, 72, 83, 84]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 49");
    crunch(2, [0, 21, 31, 45, 49, 54]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 40");
    crunch(2, [0, 4, 7, 9, 10]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 7");
    crunch(2, [0, 1, 3, 4, 9]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 6");
    
    var max = 0;
    var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var avg = [];
    
    var score = typeof process.argv[2] === 'undefined' ? 60 : process.argv[2];

    for(j = 0; j<10; j++){
        var arr = []; for(let i of cities(score)) arr.push(i);
        var plants = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * arr.length);
        console.log(`Running: Test:${j} Plants: ${plants}, Cities ${arr.length}, Score: ${score}`);
        // console.log(`City Array: [${arr}]`);
        var t0 = performance.now();
        crunch(plants,arr);
        var t1 = performance.now();
        time = (t1-t0)/1000;
        console.log(`Time Taken = ${time} seconds`);
        avg.push(time);
        max = Math.max(time,max);
        min = Math.min(time,min);
    }
    console.log(`Bench: ${avg.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)/avg.length} Max: ${max} Min: ${min} Total: ${avg.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)}`);
} else {
    var plants = process.argv[2];
    var arr = process.argv.slice(3);
    console.log(`Running: Plants: ${plants}, Cities ${arr.length}`);
    var t0 = performance.now();
    crunch(plants,arr);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    time = (t1-t0)/1000;
    console.log(`Time Taken = ${time} seconds`);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5Vhtb9s2EP5s/wquyCqplh3LTtLGihN03QsCbGnRBh0Gz2hlmZaZ2pJHyXmZ69@e3ZGiREm242LYpxltRB2Px7vj3XNH3Xi3XuxztkiaYTSmj49@FMYJWS0on0R87oU@XZM@4fSvJePUNJD@aRpFX2LDcut1f@bFMXnDkodVvSaW8qWfRNz0gWSTGZ0kNuEsmMKDWcBTS6Ysbn3CaRCLDzcjsnBM74HKchIKAErysKDRhMi3fp8YS2CdsJCODXJB2qQnJJGm4MhXi43z5enrxvVyrqk0WtfrtYAm4tW0VpwmSx6SXHd37UoGoXOZQxAzFtSpzCH0BAYCP@QR25eZBFFxxUoS/rFWBffgQ2OTwsRfxag8IZ7AWq/derMlfTvZptg6O9soDKmfsChciQ30QxbHK4y1ZzQMkqmdbio48ccm5i7na5z4kyqMWZxg3IG6bTebXxM6iyl5YsGTgVJYrn6/ecm05Y1iU0WB8LG2dza69TiZerMJbCUWTWaR8AMaf9jRloDhkkq@Jx1yRpyNps69IGTJcoyqC7HNXBeZDU1Jb4CAJ3yBqiV0vsAE0pa637itEHEOricXOOyJ99L29aI4EUrofHzLDuOFfM/2kushrlTMK85yCCq6nh@ZlDJzLl5LgJxbqKa5vmq/4HD/jUXysSWfBFnPp194tFyUwLLVavlZmsUVdbU5xMz8DZEuA7u5d6@iEoZlmS45PFzGNAaRlHyUupIkEs5F0hQinwLw/6iMhTmk/wqZgHAo0TAXWAFFTSsFfKhG5bju1UH5ywSFyzgHmwtxOhFZBfDad@ybvmBpOq7LGo1SHuGvQshRR@yq6Ta4GVZw4evXTWz5MZOzvqhdm5BjxKn3xa1MrSuU3TuImldectNsFolp7qQP8N97AfRPOLCtHPh/c1@jsct9EOYJ80k02Z59aeSG9E5mbYkTFFiYpm8zq3@OPHmlNP0MNGxm60tkTbAsK0PDWryYMSz9hRqjWqGy3S1w@vhS9Bx@/9xvZagDx6LQ6b5YhqSoM9IunYG0bluRS4vXBg3kjFvg1o@iclRCgaEOm0V8KwKBW5nUo9ytIHkZ9MrbW7KbExlDw4Ryc2N7kqKY4NirS1GsVQdxOl5CVTM9ewSR4fX77YtRflA9Lx83NLrd3lhhiyAr9iwU0i1lR8PZJPqQcBYG/1WIoaxCvdx99voyUBkWGUZOzWBLNH/sTFbnKm7hysYG3TElQWvlDJOd@fnm1kWelz2DGO7aqh6WYVyMel7DaBqNkW0YFvQ@xp@hseNs4JF1AnAqk2UolCE@h9HUXMy8MIltvEowivBSQ9MnEcQXGDkYqvaBk5j9TeWlCBgLeSZJ@ZxEHrxiMdvjHDQnZQSSkygSOQas4QwtqxXPGFjbtgt7NFVzh0oEiHSwUxH1pO6SC8/IlVadO@mg2UwPSCxvpZimIlXdG6IZbc2iwPz8O9wlobUQEHNF6ZiOe@RgJdeqLF1/tor@HLEggBZFKiV4hTfTU5AEEbxmQMAhwSDI7Bu2Imjtoc0NBm05Lsp@QbgXBpSYEBwcrqo0HMPllc1ZYqVd9t2UzdQ8gCkwiMKXXjeQk3xXKozPn8uJZpOcA/pq7foDo7MxEbIympQMMe1AxGl3CzEE7cbR3LReOO125tWC/mmEmLEfcWx4a5hFYfGaIoaL6M7s2ILt8BjrkAhHubu4cNVSU0OpN5qRWt0nJuzfhj44tNCcWk0zxP13ltRzKF7wyKdx3PJ4cDvoDregcZpdjj1o26RjkyObnNjk1TAVqofbszcR55AX5HUY31HeI07nmWKTUrpCigP/8AHPDgrFJ0juwrjb2Utwp1sSfKwEd6V6UrpztJe0srCTqjCw2jmG/zDunKaqwvgImI6AfgRsR0A/BtoJjF@COa9g9av9FDg6LWkAywepZ7pqCxS/p7j2ZnFgxEubnKL395LzcrMY6RgQdrqXlBMlpZ53Mff5NwdBYJhBV8v5iPLWu7cfLq8vP/706fLq58ury@s/cj7vNtCgPMdzTLL8o0QhrjvDDd8nTvBLVIkt7ZYQdG@EduTmzMG/hZootOBcaqFVUdhWIkMKDBZytRbLeGqyUg2XQF5EjCyDVdpC7qOAtI3NBRTQ/f0yDKHh6JFrgOvewepmTd4J4Qjycpu1jR8NEbEOVrlAoH5ANZFP6CtqgNrj8LC4DX51JK859x56ZCDErIefS0YlbTBI@5bZCgH@dL0LNRpLaWm9s3t9wuZ4wmbiNJO2dYjwuMUp18h57X2hGFIHK1y4JjEFnnGsaw2xJM8HOTR6qdPFWbvYiMlolRwsTDlYuL0K/0DBdvQ17llqhKD5AXtwIj0aEHyPvLAnjFkoxixck@so8Wa7pMhCrn@yKoRbJd6L8axPp@1Ld0N650G3Z6h91nqeXVGyLUKeio6tkfFNUbF@fHx0/gE)

Run the same way as the other one.

## [JavaScript (ES6) (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), pretest score = 12

Outline of the algorithm:

The program first maps the Data into the City Class, which maps a few data points:

- city - the absolute distance of the city
- left - the distance of the closest city to the left
- right - distance of the closest city to the right
- index - (deprecated) index in original city array

the array is then thrown into the Group class, which has the following:

- cities - the city array
- dist - the distance spanning the group
- max - the largest left connection in the group
- split()

  - returns an array containing sub groups split along the largest connection connected to the center city in the group
  - if there are 2 center nodes (an even length group) it chooses from those 3 connections
  - (*note*: this will drop any groups with less than two cities)
- center()

  - returns the best wire value for the group
  - working on a solution to skip iterating over each city left for this step
  - now with 50% less mapping

Now the algorithm proceeds to split the groups as long as it has 2 or more 
power plants to place.

Finally it maps the groups to the it's centers, and sums them all up.

### How to run:

#### Run using Node.js (v9.2.0 is what was used for creation)

running the program using generated test cases for score 70:

```javascript
node program.js 70
```

running the program using 1 power plant and cities [0,3,5]:

```javascript
node program.js 1 0 3 5
```

### Code:

```javascript
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');

class City{
	constructor(city, left, right, i){
		this._city = city;
		this._index = i;
		this._left = typeof left === 'undefined' ? 0 : city - left;
		this._right = typeof right === 'undefined' ? 0 : right - city;
	}

	get city(){return this._city;};
	get index(){return this._index;};
	get left(){return this._left;};
    get right(){return this._right;};
    set left(left){this._left = left};
    set right(right){this._right = right};

	valueOf(){return this._left;};
}

class Group{
	constructor(...cities){
        this._cities = cities;
        // console.log(cities.map(a=>a.city).reduce((a,b)=>a===''?a+(b<10?' '+b:b):a+'-'+(b<10?' '+b:b),""));
        // console.log(cities.map(a=>a.left).reduce((a,b)=>a===''?a+(b<10?' '+b:b):a+'-'+(b<10?' '+b:b),""));
        // console.log(cities.map(a=>a.right).reduce((a,b)=>a===''?a+(b<10?' '+b:b):a+'-'+(b<10?' '+b:b),""));
        // console.log("+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==")
		this._dist = cities[cities.length-1].city - cities[0].city;
		this._max = Math.max(...cities); //uses the ValueOf to get the highest Distance to the Left
	}

	get dist(){return this._dist;};
	get cities(){return this._cities;};
	get max(){return this._max;};

	split(){
        //var index = this.cities.findIndex(city=>city.left == this.max);
        //this.cities[index].left = 0;
        // console.log(`Slicing-${this.max}-${index}------`)
        var centerIndex = this.cities.length / 2;
        var splitIndex = Math.floor(centerIndex);
        if(centerIndex%1 > 0){
            var center = this.cities[splitIndex];
            if(center.right > center.left){

                splitIndex++;
            }
        } else {
            var right = this.cities[splitIndex];
            var left = this.cities[splitIndex-1];
            if(left.left > Math.max(right.right,right.left)){
               
                splitIndex--;
            } else if(right.right > Math.max(left.left,left.right)){
                
                splitIndex++;
            }
        }
        // console.log(splitIndex);
        this.cities[splitIndex].left = 0;
        this.cities[splitIndex-1].right = 0;
        var leftCities = [...this.cities.slice(0,splitIndex)];
        var rightCities = [...this.cities.slice(splitIndex)];

        // var center = this.cities[]

        if(leftCities.length <= 1){
            if(rightCities.length <= 1){
                return [];
            }
            return [new Group(...rightCities)]
        }
        if(rightCities.length <= 1){
            return [new Group(...leftCities)];
        }
        return [new Group(...leftCities), new Group(...rightCities)];
	}

    center(){
        if(typeof this._center === 'undefined'){
            if(this.cities.length == 1){
                return [0];
            }
            if(this.cities.length == 2){
                return this.cities[1].left;
            }
            var index = Math.floor(this.cities.length/2);
            this._center = this.cities.reduce((a,b)=> {
                // console.log(`${a} + (${b.city} - ${city.city})`);
                return a + Math.abs(b.city - this.cities[index].city);
            },0);
            // console.log(this._center);
        }
        
        return this._center;
    }

	valueOf(){return this._max;};
}

function crunch(plants, cities){
	var found = [];
    var size = cities.length;
    cities = cities.map((city,i,arr)=> new City(city,arr[i-1],arr[i+1],i));
	var groups = [new Group(...cities)];

	// console.log(groups);
    for(;plants>1;plants--){
        var mapped = groups.map(g=>g.center()-g.max);
        var largest = Math.max(...groups);
        // console.log('Largest:',largest)
        // console.log(...mapped);
		var index = groups.findIndex((g,i)=> mapped[i] == g.center() - g.max && g.max == largest);
		// console.log(index);
        groups = index == 0 ? 
            [...groups[index].split(),...groups.slice(index+1)]:
            [...groups.slice(0,index),...groups[index].split(),...groups.slice(index+1)];
    }
    // console.log(`=Cities=${size}================`);
    // console.log(groups);
    size = groups.map(g=>g.cities.length).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0);
    
    // console.log(`=Cities=${size}================`);
    var wires = groups.map(g=>g.center());
    
    // console.log(...wires);
    // console.log(`=Cities=${size}================`);
    console.log(`Wire Length Needed: ${wires.reduce((a,b)=>a + b,0)}`);
}

function biggestGroup(groups){
	return groups.find(g => g[g.length-1].orig - g[0].orig);
}

function* range (start, end, limit) {
    while (start < end || typeof limit !== 'undefined' && limit-- > 0) {
        yield start
        start += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }
}

function* cities (score){
	let n = Math.floor(Math.pow(2,score/5));
	var start = 0;
	while (n-- > 0 && start <= (1000 * n)) {
		yield start;
        start += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    }
}

if(typeof process.argv[3] === 'undefined'){
    crunch(1,[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 12");
    crunch(3,[0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 30, 32]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 23");
    crunch(5,[0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 3");
    crunch(6,[0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 14, 15, 18, 29, 30, 38, 41, 45, 46, 49, 58, 66, 72, 83, 84]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 49");
    crunch(2, [0, 21, 31, 45, 49, 54]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 40");
    crunch(2, [0, 4, 7, 9, 10]);
    console.log("Correct Answer: 7");
    
    var max = 0;
    var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var avg = [];
    
    var score = typeof process.argv[2] === 'undefined' ? 60 : process.argv[2];

    for(j = 0; j<10; j++){
        var arr = []; for(let i of cities(score)) arr.push(i);
        var plants = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * arr.length);
        console.log(`Running: Test:${j} Plants: ${plants}, Cities ${arr.length}, Score: ${score}`);
        var t0 = performance.now();
        crunch(plants,arr);
        var t1 = performance.now();
        time = (t1-t0)/1000;
        console.log(`Time Taken = ${time} seconds`);
        avg.push(time);
        max = Math.max(time,max);
        min = Math.min(time,min);
    }
    console.log(`Bench: ${avg.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)/avg.length} Max: ${max} Min: ${min} Total: ${avg.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)}`);
} else {
    var plants = process.argv[2];
    var arr = process.argv.slice(3);
    console.log(`Running: Plants: ${plants}, Cities ${arr.length}`);
    var t0 = performance.now();
    crunch(plants,arr);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    time = (t1-t0)/1000;
    console.log(`Time Taken = ${time} seconds`);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVh7b9s2EP/b/hRckNVSLTuWnaRtXKfYsgcCtGmxBh0Gw2hkm5aZOpInyXnM1WfP7khKImnJcTdsRmLR5N3vHrw7HnXt3XrxJGLLpBWEU/r4OAmDOCHrJY1mYXTjBROakgGJ6J8rFlGrgfOf52H4JW7Y/Xp9svDimJyx5GFdr3HWaDVJwsiawJRDFnSWOCRi/hwezAaaWjJncfszLgMsPvr5JAum9B5mWTGFADCTPCxpOCPi12BAGisgnbGAThvkDemQE45EWpyi4OaCC3b5s5RfrLUyjdJ6vebThP@07HVEk1UUkEL3ftoXBFxnk4JP5iSok0nB9QQCAh@k4eJNIj6ZUcUZEn7Za809@FDIBBj/zggzT/AnkNZrt95iRd/PqhRLs739NQpXS2Nz2@02OIHRGHaUyE/uG5gWOwuDfr58cEAQIVzQ9iL0LbHcvvGWljc49RDuwW5HdLqaUMvynLENs7BTjcYbr2mNX7udNw3SaI5PxvaJ12y0Gsaks7dn2ztL4y7836SJjfjPxO01B4Mn//bsPCmmLE7yDRpKZRc08JN5yx21ZSLJ5Y6YKFLqxsMMfeclczDwXomEPui1imHvkzkln0RwkSTk0Y1Tc/ACBck/gXisKriG829hL4p8Q@XMkMS5PJmEtJKUxGjLiFAzgwKm@jzu4@WCoQjFnbdeRLLaw6mlU6BATM95fqMPBqf43ZY1SBACqrYxCveQI44kPelU7t/VxwWbsMBv7a8zzBTGnD1t8c@VnTOjrhMaJDQ6L9FYbCM5IN2@xsGNzhj45s0WIVbpAkmxg83Uhe9dcko6isN0NXQNhoWkUV/jyEFFPgCm/CnqWV0j5pUsR2o2dag0/5USuogp2dQtr/y7qIYM2UFTSg95sWEMMojNPS3SgYsVBjpizK0znAefLda2Woa1wkYQqaCrQnNNHD4S5WZTJPlnHq4K24JZiZwKd5ckQaWj29nWdfQQRoiz7HQZQt1R4z6GFKJWx1GUGunsHPUJfp1bNbwy3Ef1uhETZ1omvh4Q19iKbCOfJMSPrGHDUdX@qEQBvRPHNZZlRYY9KtnOndUoRS8sVR1doD/F5JBqZUX7hSjC5WqxBq1lMycLv9wUvafb9HhJkRxs93hnq8srIbvVkGrcuCIntolQTyWlZG@KPejaOo7uGu2A0JsQsqmreTjtr72UNIm1vx7zTiCF3mB/zU9C/tO@MoQrBnvAyDX3xrE1zjqLkjOSd3@GL5yOMWNophppl4Vgvcz9kkHQp9VtsGwXgGK2CiYJCwMyiWA0t5YLL0hih@QNcA03ahZC9GFhkVHDD132F80bLblXYtXoknmrKG5MzPGiCHcG0wOvVWIaJocMiqMYNGHAsCPkon1MIl7UtJSa5NlUrxmuExzSaXDLs/rCqFNXDlotJYpRBii4pGifYOUK@4NTv51laMs3eiFesr3Ip7zZVPtFTXrJxjbeCraThiMB7CpSQBOaoS9qasJIPYsOzvLBZeBXQT9kI0zWQn@IS24BefZMDmA5E4/ghmRmHHz5JkgF4PiCi6UWv8Pc9izsZSvq5AvyHOLLTdcenVQA5OedUMP5duQsAcpSfiAK8WB/jRGcDoxPlvDbgkqG/ka0qKmwcSNqjvOc/zd6YRjcsYjnV1W4bhEDLuPc5VbuqoTG8zvgwT2HHxEXlE7p9ARqKJdi@gAqJnohRRy1@IyZj6Eoslu6GkqPrFlKtFs@gSj3h75ypQvheMUAx9scjnXs5yTyAp8SC@5lUeIQGkwdsmA3LLHl@XA3Z4tsnbxGAvL1a/5OBinJd8ZLFUgjvtBq8cuDctA8MLqYEo6VzwnkJhzI2Ykhzjo@BO2m4Y1lP3c7WXikuv6ynFrxJIwoumUBd8BAPzb5cBneWV2Hkx0c5QVUSOcNZ02aGgi90Qxp9YBYIL9DnpPARnNqNcWQ/r@zpGhqllE4oXHchsJzO@yNKvoaeRK5zrDjkK5DDh1y7JCXo5LY2zsLo4hOEvJDEN/R6IS43b2MTKD0OIoLf/iAZxdB8QnIPRj3ujsBd3sG8FEG3BPqCXT3cCc0E@x4Ewysdo/gH8bdV1JVGB8C0SHMHwLZIcwfwdwxjF@AOS@B@@VuChy@MjQA9qH0TC8TgfA7wnXK4cCIFw55hd7fCefFnlq6xNF8X1yW@ATD0L9Y3Yzhcv3h/cfzy/NPP38@v/jl/OL88o@Czrv1lYal6FowO4p3plpEdkclb0@P8fWpQSZvT9hbXHPtyPVrF7@bTaOzgIZGaMGJMXEZAbHyNY/IaBup2stVPLeY0WKIfkVP9Tz1snyDpEUAeewUAFqR/m0VBCzwT8gl9h776@uUfODgWKuFmNQh8gYJXXEOCLMfUU2k4/qmV4aSSQcUVF6otwOoQ6oeWmeJDaDB727nT9gN7piVuK2kYx9gnaow8hIpL70vFENkf42MKYkp0ExjVWuIDeFvpFDmjbd/uOrofZ@IPkHBAknBAlttODSVfqRgO/oOZZZ1BAe4IF0NwPdIi@/IyDsW8DELUnIZJt5iG4o4UdXXRVr4bMSvHp/qsmylemUnfR5EO4aO2rNsi5KqCHkqOioj45uiIn18fHT/Bg)

I will clean up the commented out code over the next couple of days as I am still working on this, just wanted to see if this was passing more than just the small cases.

Comment: Consider the testcase `K = 2, A = [0, 21, 31, 45, 49, 54]`. The correct answer is 40, but your program outputs 51.

Comment: Even simpler: `K = 2, A = [0, 4, 7, 9, 10]`. Correct: 7, your answer: 8.

Comment: Okay It should be working now... It at least works for all provided cases.

Comment: Actually I also may have derived another algorithm that works better. I'm going to test the theory and post it in a bit.

Comment: Still not working... `K = 2, A = [0, 1, 3, 4, 9]`. Correct: 6, your answer: 7.

Comment: Last attempt at this, I have other projects to get to :/

Comment: `K = 2, A = [0, 1, 4, 9]`. Correct: 4, your answer: 6.

Answer (score 1):

## C (non-competing, pretest score = 76)

This is an attempt to translate @AndersKaseorg's second Rust solution to C.

```
typedef void V;typedef char C;typedef long L;
#define R return
#define W while
#define S static
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#define exit(x)     ({L r;asm volatile("syscall":"=a"(r):"0"(SYS_exit ),"D"(x)              :"cc","rcx","r11","memory");r;})
#define read(x,y,z) ({L r;asm volatile("syscall":"=a"(r):"0"(SYS_read ),"D"(x),"S"(y),"d"(z):"cc","rcx","r11","memory");r;})
#define write(x,y,z)({L r;asm volatile("syscall":"=a"(r):"0"(SYS_write),"D"(x),"S"(y),"d"(z):"cc","rcx","r11","memory");r;})
S V P(L x){C s[32],*p=s+32;*--p='\n';do{*--p='0'+x%10;x/=10;}W(x);write(1,p,s+32-p);}
#define N 0x100000 //max
#define INF (-1ul>>1)
S L cost[N],nk1,*am; //nk1:n-k+1, am:input's partial sums offset with the current "m" in _start()
S L f(L i,L j){if(i+1>=j&&cost[j]!=INF){L h=(i-j+1)>>1;R cost[j]+am[i+1]-am[j+h]-am[i-h+1]+am[j];}else{R INF;}}
S V smawk(L sh,L*c,L nc,L*r){ //sh:shift,c:cols,r:result
 L n=nk1>>sh;if(!n)R;
 L m=n>>1,u[m];
 if(n<nc){
  L ns=0,s[nc],sk[nc],*skp=sk;
  for(L jk=0;jk<nc;jk++){
   L j=c[jk];W(ns>0&&f(~(~(ns-1)<<sh),j)<=f(~(~(ns-1)<<sh),s[ns-1])){--ns;--skp;}
   if(ns<n){s[ns++]=j;*skp++=jk;}
  }
  smawk(sh+1,s,ns,u);for(L i=0;i<m;i++)u[i]=sk[u[i]];
 }else{
  smawk(sh+1,c,nc,u);
 }
 L l=0,ish=(1<<sh)-1,dsh=1<<(sh+1);
 for(L i=0;i<m;i++){
  L k=u[i],bj=l,bc=f(ish,c[l]);
  for(L j=l+1;j<=k;j++){L h=f(ish,c[j]);if(h<bc){bc=h;bj=j;}}
  *r++=bj;*r++=k;l=k;ish+=dsh;
 }
 if(n&1){
  L nsh=~(~(n-1)<<sh),bj=l,bc=f(nsh,c[l]);
  for(L j=l+1;j<nc;j++){L h=f(nsh,c[j]);if(h<bc){bc=h;bj=j;}}
  *r=bj;
 }
}
S L inp(L*a){
 L n=-1,l,v=0;C b[1<<20];
 W(0<(l=read(0,b,sizeof(b))))for(L i=0;i<l;i++)if('0'<=b[i]&&b[i]<='9'){v=b[i]-'0'+10*v;}else{a[++n]=v;v=0;}
 R n;
}
V _start(){
 S L a[N];L n=inp(a),k=*a,s=0;for(L i=0;i<n;i++){a[i]=s;s+=a[i+1];}a[n]=s;
 *cost=0;for(L i=1,l=n+1-k;i<l;i++)cost[i]=INF;
 S L c[N];L nc=n+1-k;for(L i=0;i<nc;i++)c[i]=i;
 S L r[N];nk1=n-k+1;for(L m=0;m<k;m++){am=a+m;smawk(0,c,nc,r);for(L i=n-k;i>=0;i--)cost[i]=f(i,r[i]);}
 P(cost[n-k]);exit(0);
}
```

Compile with:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
clang -O3 -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-unwind-tables -fno-unroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -oa a.c
strip -R.comment -R'.note*' a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean), score = 65

```
module main
import StdEnv, System.IO

parseArgs :: *World -> ((Int, {#Int}), *World)
parseArgs world
    # (args, world)
        = nextArgs [] world
    # args
        = reverse args
    # (k, a)
        = (hd args, tl args)
    = ((toInt k, {toInt n \\ n <- a}), world)
where
    nextArgs :: [String] *World -> ([String], *World)
    nextArgs args world
        # (arg, world)
            = evalIO getLine world
        | arg == ""
            = (args, world)
        = nextArgs [arg:args] world

minimalWeight :: Int !{#Int} -> Int
minimalWeight k a
    # count
        = size a
    # touches
        = createArray ((count - k + 3) / 2 * k) 0
    = treeWalk k count a [(0, 0, 0, 0)] touches
where
    treeWalk :: Int !Int {#Int} ![(!Int, !Int, Int, Int)] *{Int} -> Int
    treeWalk k verticies a [(weight, vertex, degree, requires) : nodes] touches
        | vertex >= verticies
            = weight
        | requires >= k
            = treeWalk k verticies a nodes touches
        # index
            = degree * k + requires
        | (select touches index) > vertex
            = treeWalk k verticies a nodes touches
        # (next, pivot)
            = (vertex + 1 + degree, verticies + requires)
        # (nodes, touches)
            = (orderedPrepend (weight, next, 0, requires + 1) nodes, update touches index (vertex + 1))
        | pivot >= k + next
            # (weight, vertex)
                = (weight + (select a next) - (select a vertex), vertex + 1)
            # nodes
                = orderedPrepend (weight, next + 1, 0, requires + 1) nodes
            | pivot == k + next
                = treeWalk k verticies a nodes touches
            # weight
                = weight + (select a (next + 1)) - (select a vertex)
            # nodes
                = orderedPrepend (weight, vertex, degree + 1, requires) nodes
            = treeWalk k verticies a nodes touches
        = treeWalk k verticies a nodes touches
    where
        orderedPrepend :: (!Int, Int, Int, Int) ![(!Int, Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
        orderedPrepend a []
            = [a]
        orderedPrepend a [b : b_]
            # (x, _, _, _)
                = a
            # (y, _, _, _)
                = b
            | y > x
                = [a, b : b_]
            = [b : orderedPrepend a b_]

Start world
    # ((k, a), world)
        = parseArgs world
    = minimalWeight k a
```

Compile with:
`clm -h 1024M -gci 32M -gcf 32 -s 32M -t -nci -ou -fusion -dynamics -IL Platform main`

Takes `K`, and then each element of `A`, as command-line arguments.

Comment: @ColeraSu May I ask what the deciding factor was in the score? Correctness / Time / Memory? I hope it was Time.

Comment: You are right, it was time.